# How to hide mat-tab-header with nested tab groups, hide for outer mat-tab-group without hiding for inner

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I have html essentially

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab>
        <mat-tab-group>
            <mat-tab>
            </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

How can I use css (or any method really) to hide the outer tabs groups mat-tab-header element, but not affect the inner tab header?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out, just had to select direct child

```
<mat-tab-group class="invisible-tabs">
    <mat-tab>
        <mat-tab-group>
            <mat-tab>
            </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

.invisible-tabs {
  > .mat-tab-header {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does not work at all for me

Comment: Works perfectly if yout put the .invisible-tabs class in your styles.scss. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

I highly recommend you to use this custom directive instead of using css.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[header-less-tabs]",
})
export class HeaderLessTabsDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(private eleRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.eleRef.nativeElement.children[0].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

It's very simple and reusable.
usage example:

```
<mat-tab-group header-less-tabs>
    <mat-tab>
        <mat-tab-group>
            <mat-tab>
            </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Apart from reusability, can you explain why it's recommended to use a directive instead of css?

Comment: One of the other ways is using ng-deep or setting view encapsulation to none. But it will affect other tabs as well and directive won't have that issue. Besides that, reusability is a strong factor for me

Answer (score 2):

SIMPLE ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:

Add the following to your component css file:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-header {
display: none!important;
}
```

Comment: This hides all tab-headers and is therefore not a relevant solution to the question. Also ::ng-deep is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

Comment: I see ng-deep will no longer work in the future, i still don't find an alternative to edit the component styles from a parent component but passing it through properties and then styling it inside the component, do you know any other alternative @lionthefox?

Comment: In your styles.scse, instead of ::ng-deep use the compoment selector. For example if you component is called TestComponent and the selector is app-test, write: app-test .mat-tab-header {...}. This way the class will only be overwritten in the desired component.

Answer (score 0):

### ANOTHER ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION using ng:deep

```
 <mat-tab-group >
            <mat-tab class="invisible-tabs">
                    </mat-tab>
        
                    <mat-tab class="invisible-tabs">
                    </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>

    <!-- in css file -->
    .invisible-tabs {
          ::ng-deep .mat-tab-header {
            display: none !important;
          }
        }
```